# EFI grub vanished, how to get it back?

Tags: fedora, boot, windows, grub2, uefi

I have a dual boot (Fedora & Windows 10), after a glitch from Windows, the machine only boots using the Windows' boot loader and not grub2 as before.

*How can I get grub2 back?*

What I tried:

```
$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.5.7-300.fc24.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.5.7-300.fc24.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.4.4-301.fc23.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-f4a99c4a747b4f928c2ad16c434a731d
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-f4a99c4a747b4f928c2ad16c434a731d.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-b80563ee4ffb43768b1936a46d9cd0d5
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-b80563ee4ffb43768b1936a46d9cd0d5.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
```

After a reboot, straight back into Windows.

```
[root@nightwatch] # efibootmgr -v         
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0000,0003,0001,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,d602a4af-b36c-4bf9-83b4-5d93295600bb,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...,................
Boot0001  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.H.i.t.a.c.h.i. .H.D.S.7.2.1.0.1.0.C.L.A.3.3.2....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . .P.J.9.2.1.2.Q.H.7.1.7.G.A.M........BO..NO........o.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.4.0. .E.V.O. .1.T.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.S.9.D.S.N.F.A.1.7.5.5.8.7. .F. . . . ........BO..NO........o.H.i.t.a.c.h.i. .H.D.T.7.2.1.0.1.0.S.L.A.3.6.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . .T.S.6.F.7.0.H.M.X.2.K.W.K.4........BO..NO........o.H.i.t.a.c.h.i. .H.D.S.7.2.2.0.2.0.A.L.A.3.3.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . .K.J.1.1.0.7.B.Y.X.H.P.Y.D.9........BO..NO........o.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.5.0. .E.V.O. .5.0.0.G.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.S.J.1.S.N.G.A.5.2.1.8.6.7. .J. . . . ........BO
Boot0002  CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.T.S.S.T.c.o.r.p. .C.D.D.V.D.W. .S.H.-.2.2.4.D.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.R.8.6.Y.6.F.A.0.B.5.0.Z.1. . . . . . ........BO
Boot0003* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell  VenMedia(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012)..BO
Boot0006* UEFI: (FAT) TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-224DB  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(4,65535,0)/CDROM(1,0x59,0x1680)..BO
```

This is more promising. There is no grub2 entry there…

Finally, in case that helps:

```
; df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.9G  1.9M  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.9G  1.5M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G   12G   36G  25% /
tmpfs                    7.9G  1.4M  7.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb2                477M  184M  264M  42% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  865G   71G  751G   9% /home
/dev/sdb1                200M   45M  155M  23% /boot/efi
tmpfs                    1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd1                1.9T  979G  885G  53% /media/Backups
/dev/sdc1                932G  474G  459G  51% /media/MediaVault
/dev/sda2                444G   46G  398G  11% /media/DataVault
```

The last three are windows shares mounted. It's sadly easier to mount windows disk on linux than the other way round.

After running `grub2-install /dev/sdb`, grub2 does indeed load but cannot find any OS to boot.

*How to fix that?*

In addition, [this information was gathered via rescutux disk](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24468462/) but it failed to rescue the boot for me.

Comment: Should this go to [server fault](https://serverfault.com)? I can never tell on those question which saddle two sites…

Comment: if you are not a professional sysadmin configuring a system for professional use then you should never ask on [sf].

Comment: @terdon That makes some sense… Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that fedora boot entry in EFI was lost somehow.

To get fedora boot entry back, you can reinstall grub2 to disk in root shell:

```
grub2-install <YOUR_HDD_DEVICE>
```

For example: `grub2-install /dev/sda`

And make sure there's a working `grub.cfg` file under `/boot/grub2`, if there's no such file, you can regenerate it in root shell via

- `grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
- or `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: I had to copy the `grubenv` file manually as grub was complaining it could not find it.

Comment: Mine is a symbolic link to `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv` file. `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    28 12月  8 23:50 grubenv -> /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv`

Comment: That's what mine was as well but `/boot/efi` is apparently not mounted at the time grub boots. I was getting `error: /grub2/grubenv not found\n Press Any Key To Conitnue`.